# Logical difference between the two approaches. (Count ways to reach the n'th stair)

Tags: c++, logic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to count the number of ways to reach the nth stair, starting from the first stair and going up either one or two stairs at a time. The first approach below works fine, but the second does not.

```
//---01--------
int mod = (int)1e9+7;
int prev1 = 1;
int prev2 = 1;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    prev2 = (prev2 + prev1) % mod;
    prev1 = prev2 - prev1;
}
return prev2;
```

```
//---02--------
int mod = (int)1e9+7;
int prev1 = 1;
int prev2 = 1;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    int curr = (prev2 + prev1) % mod;
    prev1 = prev2;
    prev2 = curr;
}
return prev2;
```

The second approach doesn't work with large n.

**Sample Input Case:** n = 87

**Output with the second approach:**

-334512466

**Expected Output:**

665487541

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: [Works the other way round](https://godbolt.org/z/1MrsoE9Mn) for me. The first approach overflows, the second works fine.

Comment: Let's say `prev1` and `prev2` are both `mod-1`. Then `(prev2 + prev1) % mod == mod-2`, and subtracting `prev1` from that produces a negative number. I imagine this throws off further computations. The second algorithm doesn't require subtracting a larger number from a smaller number.

Comment: both solutions are not the same **because** of the remainder operation - they will give same result as long as the sum is less than `mod` - not sure why you are using the remainder operation, maybe the intention is to do `(prev1 % mod) + (prev2 % mod)` ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its other way around, your first solution will overflow(not Integer overflow but negative values due to wrong logic) but not second one.

For better understanding see below updated code for your first solution -

```
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.println("i : "+i);
    prev2 = (prev2 + prev1) % mod;
    System.out.println("P2 : " +prev2);
    System.out.println("P1 : " +prev1);
    prev1 = prev2 - prev1;
}
```

Below is the output of above -

```
i : 44
P2 : 134903163
P1 : 433494437
i : 45
P2 : -163688111
P1 : -298591274
```

If you observe the values you can see, for i=44, prev2 is smaller then prev1 because of mod function and when you will do  `prev1 = prev2 - prev1;` you will get negative value so this solution is wrong.

While second solution will work as there is no such case.

Comment: Correct, first one is over flowing while second one is not.

Comment: @Thomson do you mean there is an `int` overflow? That is not the case, it is just that the sum is greater than `mod` for `i==44` and `prev2 < prev1` so `prev2-prev1 < 0`

Comment: its not int overflow to be exact, as described by @tomar it because of minus operation, due to mod function prev2 becoming less than prev1 which is resulting in negative value. So ideally its not overflow, its wrong implementation.

Comment: @Thomson  then I wonder why you wrote "first one is over flowing..." (and even got a upvote??), kind of confusing - that was the reason for my comment (I know what the problem is - as commented already)